# CD Linking Log not generating in Tridion 2009

Tags: content-delivery, 2009, linking, dynamic-linking

A Page on our website is showing an incorrect (old) link through Dynamic Linking, when I check in the Broker the linking info in the database is correct, but that info is not used on the web page. Where do I need to look for this problem?

I have checked the `Link_Info` and the `Dynamic_Linking` tables in database where the destination (comp id) and source (dedicated page url) is fine.

Also, I would like to see the linking information in the log file, in the `cd_link.conf` file the logging is present but not generating the log.

If I change the config file, do I need to restart any services?

Is there any other log (file/database) from where I can check the linking information (component/dynamic)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your website is showing old linking information, this usually means you have a caching problem. Best way to check if it is related to an outdated cache, is to restart your web/application server (SDL Tridion Broker cache is memory based, so it will be cleared after a restart) and check the page again. After the restart when you request the page, you should see the correct link (that what you saw in your database), if not, then the configuration on the website is not pointing towards the right database most likely.

If you issue is with caching, then you most likely have an issue with the cache invalidation propagation, or simply put, with your Cache Channel Service (which takes care of propagating the cache invalidation messages from the Deployer to the Broker).

To get more information out of your logfile, set the log level to `Debug` and after that restart your Content Delivery services (if available) and your web/application server. Please note that a standard Content Delivery setup, usually consists of at least two parts, the Deployer and the web/application server. Both of these can have separate configuration files which need to be in sync, and both will need to be restarted after config changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr. Bart. By restarting web server, I guess it will be IIS. So do we need to restart the server or restarting the App pool/site will do? Also, If we change the log level to Debug , will it log the communication related to CCS . Please clarify.

Comment: Restarting or recycling the app pool on IIS is usually enough indeed, and there is no communication from the Linking service to the CSS, the CSS broadcasts messages that the Broker listens too. Only the Deployer will send (invalidation) messages to the CSS when a new item is deployed, they should show up in its (debug) log.

Comment: @AnupamBaksi see also this article by Julian Wraith on SDL Tridion Caching, it's an older article but the concepts are all still the same: http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/whatisthesdltridionobjectcache.aspx